# Вопрос по Bootstrap или по CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос заключается в том что сетку то есть Grid не действует padding контейнера, как это исправить,
Например на заголовку действует а сетку не действует, помогите пожалуйста
Внизу код

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#333">
        <h2 class="text-light">Grid Test</h2>
        <div class="bg-primary">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 p-1 border">Text1</div>
                <div class="col-4 p-1 border">Text2</div>
                <div class="col-4 p-1 border">Text3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 p-1 border">Text4</div>
                <div class="col-4 p-1 border">Text5</div>
                <div class="col-4 p-1 border">Text6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @entithat `col-4` так 4я. что собственно видно из путей к стилям

Comment: У контейнера есть паддинг по умолчанию, но сетку не действует, это и есть проблема

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что паддинг не действует?

Comment: У сетки нету отступ левой и правой стороне, а у заголовке есть,

Comment: @BahodirBahodir у `row` зато `margin-x: -15` который нивелирует padding контейнера.

Comment: Я заместил сетку внутри div, div закращено на синий цвет, если вы заметили сетка выходит за границы, и прилепает к краям контейнера,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию в [классе `.row`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/3cf51c6ac95c4702efc632a7983019c71f77d4b3/scss/mixins/_grid.scss#L5) есть правила `margin-left` и `margin-right`.

Добавьте `m-0` для каждого `.row`, чтобы убрать отрицательное значение, которое растягивает ряд.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#333">
        <h2 class="text-light">Grid Test</h2>
        <div class="bg-primary">
            <div class="row m-0">
                <div class="col-4 p-1 border">Text1</div>
                <div class="col-4 p-1 border">Text2</div>
                <div class="col-4 p-1 border">Text3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row m-0">
                <div class="col-4 p-1 border">Text4</div>
                <div class="col-4 p-1 border">Text5</div>
                <div class="col-4 p-1 border">Text6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Comment: @BahodirBahodir, пожалуйста